# I can't get query output from postgres database in command line?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm just trying to run a few queries on a database, however, nothing seems to appear when I run my queries. I log into my database system using:

```
psql -h HOSTNAME -U USERNAME -d DATABASENAME
```

That works fine, and I'm onto the database system. However, I get no output in my queries. I typed:

```
SELECT title AND department 
FROM jointnames 
WHERE artist = 'John Poit';
```

I typed that directly after logging in, so that was the whole statement, I don't know if you're meant to include something else along with it to generate the output?

It just comes up blank? Can anyone instruct me on the right way to query a database from a command line?

Comment: String constants need to be put in single quotes: `WHERE artist = 'john poit';` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS  Also: string comparison is case sensitive `'John Poit'` is something different then `'john poit'`

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that and got the error "argument of AND must be type boolean, not type character varying".

Comment: The `AND` in the `SELECT` list would cause that error. Column names should just be separated by commas.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get title `and` department from the table `jointnames` you separate the fields with a comma.

```
SELECT title, department 
FROM jointnames 
WHERE artist = 'John Poit';
```

The AND keyword is used select values based on more than one value, like:

```
SELECT title, department 
FROM jointnames 
WHERE artist = 'John Poit'
AND city = 'London';
```

Comment: `AND` is also a logical operator in PostgreSQL, which is why it didn't just complain of a syntax error with it being in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm just getting used to postgreSQL and little things like this are a big help

Comment: @TomH Saw you provided an answer as a comment before I posted an answer. Pardon, not my intention.

Comment: No worries :) I'm glad that you put everything all together.